# Can not figure out jquery error

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out where the error is in this. Does anyone see it?

```
$('.ask').jConfirmAction( {
    question : "Are you sure you want to delete the selected row?", 
    yesAnswer : "Yes", 
    cancelAnswer : "No", 
    onYes: function( evt ) { 
      contentpages( evt.target ); 
    }
} );

$('.ask2').jConfirmAction( {  
   question : "Are you sure you want to delete all selected rows?",  
questionClass: "question2", 
onYes: function( evt ){  
contentpages( evt.target ); 
}  
} );

function contentpages(whatsThis) {
    var contentPageID = $(whatsThis).parents('td').find('img').attr('id');
    var dataString = 'contentPageID=' + contentPageID + '&deleteContentPage=True'; 
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "processes/contentpages.php", 
        data: dataString, 
    });
    $(whatsThis).parents("tr").eq(0).hide();    
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting or is it just not working?

Comment: I'm getting this in the jshint.com error. #

Line 1$('.ask2').jConfirmAction( {  

Unexpected ' '.

Comment: jslint say the same thing. Why don't you try taking out the extra spaces between `(` and `{` and fix the comma that Ariel pointed out and run it again?

Comment: That didn't help because its still preventing other things from working. That normally work.

Comment: a jsfiddle would probably help, Jeff

Comment: Here's the fiddle and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/kcejw/ not sure about the ajax but I'm still not sure what the error is...

Comment: That worked Jen thank you. I can't see a difference. What was the change?

Comment: None other than maybe the version of jquery and the version of the plugin that I included with the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra comma here:

```
data: dataString, 
   });
```

Comment: I fixed that but that wasn't the issue because its still giving me an issue on the page.